# multiplying two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, i have 2 data frames "df1" and "df2". The df1 and df2 are as follows.

```
>df1
  date      value
1 1990-10-10  3
2 1990-10-11  2.3
3 1990-10-12  2.5

>df2
  date      value
1 1990-10-10  3
2 1990-10-11  2
3 1990-10-12  2
```

I need a third data frame "df3", that contains the same column names as df1 and df2. But the value field should be the product of values in df1 and df2.
I am expecting the following output

```
>df3
  date      value
1 1990-10-10  9
2 1990-10-11  4.6
3 1990-10-12  4
```

Is it possible in R?

Comment: I'm assuming there is a typo in the output of "df3" that you have provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the dates are identical, then you can simply use:

```
df3 <- df1
df3$value <- as.numeric(as.character(df3$value))
df3$value <- df3$value * as.numeric(as.character(df2$value))
```

If the dates are *NOT* identical in the two `data.frames`, please use `@MatthewLundberg` answer below

Comment: all dates are equal. But a warning message is displayed. Warning message:
In Ops.factor(df3$value, df2$value) : * not meaningful for factors

Comment: and the value field becomes NA

Comment: then your values are factors and not numeric.  You simply need to convert them first ;)

Comment: You must convert to `character` then to `numeric`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, thank you for catching my sloppiness!   Edited to reflect.

Comment: Dinoop, thanks for selecting this answer, howeverI think @MatthewLundberg 's is the better answer.  Especially if the dates are not all the same.

Answer (score 9):

"Merge" the long way with `rbind`, and use `aggregate` to produce the products:

```
aggregate(value ~ date, data=rbind(df1,df2), FUN=prod)
##         date value
## 1 1990-10-10   9.0
## 2 1990-10-11   4.6
## 3 1990-10-12   5.0
```

If you have mode `factor` for the `value` columns of the data frames, you'll have to convert to `character` then to `numeric` to extract the value:

```
df1$value <- as.factor(df1$value)
df2$value <- as.factor(df2$value)

aggregate(as.numeric(as.character(value)) ~ date, data=rbind(df1,df2), FUN=prod)
##         date as.numeric(as.character(value))
## 1 1990-10-10                             9.0
## 2 1990-10-11                             4.6
## 3 1990-10-12                             5.0
```

You can also convert with `as.numeric(levels(value))[value]`.  See `?factor` for details.

Comment: sir. The value field of both data frames are character. So this code shows some error. I have very few experience in language R.So please help me.

Comment: @DinoopNair, for this reason, we usually recommend using `dput(YourData)` instead of just pasting the output as you've done here and for other questions. Looking at some of your other questions, others have asked you to do so before, so please do heed this advice in the future. Thanks.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Im sorry for my mistake. For the next time onwards i will follow your words. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can `merge` the two `data.frame`s first and then proceed with `transform`:

```
> temp <- merge(df1, df2, by = "date")
> temp
        date value.x value.y
1 1990-10-10     3.0       3
2 1990-10-11     2.3       2
3 1990-10-12     2.5       2
> transform(temp, Prod = value.x * value.y)
        date value.x value.y Prod
1 1990-10-10     3.0       3  9.0
2 1990-10-11     2.3       2  4.6
3 1990-10-12     2.5       2  5.0
```

Here, since both `data.frame`s have the same column names, I've specified that we want to merge only by the "date" variable so that both "value" variables would be present in the "temp" `data.frame`.

Comment: sir. The value field of both data frames are character. So this code shows some error. I have very few experience in language R.So please help me.

Answer (score 2):

After you fix you problems with df1 and df2 having "values" of type factor which is really someting you should do before attempting this, you can do just this:

```
df3 <- data.frame( data=df1$date, value=df1[ ,"value"]*df2[ ,"value"])
```

The conversion of factors that should be numeric is covered in the R-FAQ: [FAQ 7.10](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f)

Comment: works **if** all the dates are common in both dataframes so that ``df1$value`` and ``df2$value`` have the same length, throws error otherwise.

Comment: Yes. And in the comments to other questions it became apparent (3 years ago) that the OP had serious data management issues involving factors. Question would have been solve much quicker with examples presented with dput() and including any extra complexity as you suggest might need attention.